# Related to Applying Runge-Kutta Method

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have an initial value problem (henceforth IVP) as follows:
$$\frac{d \Phi(t)}{dt}= A(t)\Phi(t)$$ subject to the initial condition $\Phi(t_0)=I$,
 where $\Phi(t), A(t), I$ are square matrices of same order and $t_0$ is the initial time.
$I$ is the identity matrix.

Runge-Kutta method says one require the initial condition to be a vector. In my case it is a identity matrix $I$.

So $(a)$ is it 4th order Runge-Kutta method applicable here $?$
   $(b)$ Is there any other way (Numerical method/Scheme)to solving the given IVP $?$

$\bullet$ Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just convert your matrix to a long vector. Or write your equation componentwise. You typically start with RK4 and then see if the solution is good. If not then look for more specialized methods.

Comment: @ Maesumi. I have atleast 1000 order matrix. i.e., size of $A(t)$ is 1000 or more. Can you please suggest how the converting to long vector will help means any example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Split your $\Phi$ and $I$ into columns, so
\begin{align}
\Phi &= \left [ \phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n\right ] \\
I &= \left [e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n \right ]
\end{align}
where $\phi_i, e_i \in \mathbb R^n,\ \forall i$.

So, instead one matrix system you'll get $n$ linear systems
$$
\frac {d \phi_i}{dt} = A(t) \phi_i(t) \\
\phi_i(t_0) = e_i
$$
for which you can apply regular RK4.

You also can do it simultaneously, since matrix multiplication is row-to-column based, i.e.
$$
A(t) \Phi (t) = \left [ A \phi_1(t), A \phi_2(t), \ldots, A \phi_n(t)\right ]
$$

Comment: @ Kaster, Thanks. It seems to be  a brilliant idea. Let me try to my system and let you   know.

Comment: @ Kaster, your idea worked.  Thank you.