# Using Runge-Kutta 4th order to solve a complex matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I'm trying to solve a differential equation of the form

\begin{equation}
\frac{dQ(t)}{dt} = - i H(t)Q(t)
\end{equation}

$Q$ and $H$ are both complex matrices. I'm using RK4. I implemented it as if I was treating a single variables so I'll define $k1,k2,k3,k4$ as matrices and do the normal RK4 calculations. I'm using armadillo library with C++ so it should be able to handle complex matrices without any problem. I'm not getting the results I'm expecting so I was wondering if the Runge-Kutta should be changed for this case?

Comment: Some clarification is needed. How are $k_1,... k_4$ related to matrices $Q$ and $H$ ? Are these matrices  $2 \times 2$ ? What are the initial values ?

Comment: Besides, give a reference (an internet site for example) to what you call "the expected results" and say what you obtain instead.

Comment: $k1,..,k4$ are matrices of the same size as $Q,H$. And I meant that I'm using 


$Q_{n+1} = Q_n + \frac{k1}{6} +\frac{k2}{3} + \frac{k3}{3} + \frac{k4}{6}$ 


where I define $ k1 = hf(t_n,Q_n)$ , $k2 = hf(t_n + 0.5h, Q_n+ 0.5k1)$, $k3 =hf(t_n + 0.5h, Q_n+ 0.5k2)$, $k4 =hf(t_n + h, Q_n+k3) $. 


$f$ is  $ -i H(t) Q(t)$. 


I'm using this for a physics calculation where I'm calculating a time dependent hamiltonian of a lattice with different chemical potential on different leads and expecting some current but all I'm getting is noise.

Comment: $h$ is the timestep

Comment: The initial values is a different time independent calculation. My results might be due to some physical reasons that I haven't quite grasped yet but I just wanted to rule out that the RK4 method is correct and doesn't need any modification.

Comment: Your step size $h$ might be too large. What is the operator norm of $H(t)$ (maximal eigenvalue if $H$ is hermitean). You might get better results using a formula with unitary updates, like $Q_{n+1}=(I+ih/2·S)^{-1}(I-ih/2·S)Q_n$ or the 4th order Padé approximant of the exponential. $S$ is some hermitean matrix related to $H(t)$ over the step interval.

Comment: Have you considered looking for an analytical solution?

Comment: As said by Rodrigo, analytical solutions can be considered: see VI and VII of the [Magnus paper](https://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~jyt/ED/magnus.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried to solve your issue like in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/473117)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I don't know if I can do the analytical solution as I have a matrix of the order 100*100 and my initial condition is a non diagonal matrix so I can't do the solution provided the question of Tapen. I'll try to verify with what Lutz suggested and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

Take $L=\max_{t\in[a,b]}\|H(t)\|_{op}$, this is the global Lipschitz constant (constant of the Lipschitz condition) of the ODE over the integration interval.

Evaluating the [stability region of the RK4 method](http://www.chebfun.org/examples/ode-linear/Regions.html) gives that one needs $Lh<2.5$ for any hope of a non-chaotic result, $Lh<1.5$ for a qualitatively reasonable result, $Lh=0.1$ for a quick graphical check and $Lh\sim 0.001$ for the optimal result in double precision 64bit floating point numbers.

---

The topic of Runge-Kutta-like methods on manifolds like the Lie groups is a well-researched one. For example, a modification/correction of RK4 is derived and tested in [Munthe-Kaas (1998): *"Runge-Kutta methods on Lie groups"*](http://hans.munthe-kaas.no/work/Blog/Entries/1998/1/1_Article:_Runge-Kutta_methods_on_Lie_groups_files/munthe-kaas98rkm.pdf).